# How to send a location to Firestore and get places based on distance?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

In my app I want to send (perhaps via a query) a user's geopoint (userLocation) whose car has broken down and he is stranded. As a response, I want to get back all repair shops that will be willing to reach the stranded user. Each Repair_Shop firestore document contains their geopoint (shopLocation) and a number in km, serviceDistance, which is their service radius (serviceRadius). I want a response with all of the documents in the Repair_Shop collection which satisfies the criteria serviceDistance <= |userLocation - shopLocation|.

I have read through the GeoFirestore document but am not quite sure how to go about implementing this. The calculation cannot be done in the front-end, naturally. But what do I send as a query and if possible what do I do on the Firestore API so that I get the expected document snapshot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with a single geoquery. The reason for that is simple: there might be a repair shop on the north pole that is willing to travel 10,000 km to service a stranded vehicle. So you'd essentially always have to request all shops, and then sort/filter them client-side.

This problem is essentially the same as:

- [How find nearest users by latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404254/how-find-nearest-users-by-latitude-and-longitude/50413605#50413605)

As I answer there, the best option is to start with a reasonable range, and query all documents within that range. If that doesn't lead to a result, try again with a larger range.

Comment: I have been looking into this. I dont know if a definitive answer exists but I think there is a possibility, albeit convoluted, via Google Cloud Functions. What do you think?

Comment: The API you use in Cloud Functions to call Firestore is not significantly different from the one you call elsewhere. What isn't possible in Android, is unlikely to be possible in Cloud Functions either.